# WCF: Not able to connect to service after enabling TLS 1.2 and disabling SSL

Tags: wcf, tls1.2

We are in process of upgrading our product to use TLS 1.2 version. To do that, we upgraded all the project from .net 4.6.2 to .net 4.7.2 version and built it.

I am seeing one issue, specific to WCF service while opening a channel

```
(proxy as ICommunicationObject).Open();
```

I have this in my code already:

```
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/#wcf47
    
AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.ServiceModel.DisableUsingServicePointManagerSecurityProtocols",
        false);
    
    AppContext.SetSwitch("Switch.System.Net.DontEnableSchUseStrongCrypto",
        false);

System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Exceptions:

> The request for security token could not be satisfied because authentication failed.
>
> The caller was not authenticated by the service.

I use Certificates (both Client and Server) for Authentication with

```
Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue after having:

Client Side:

```
b.Security.Message.EstablishSecurityContext = false;
b.Security.Message.NegotiateServiceCredential = false;
```

Server side:

```
<message clientCredentialType="Certificate" establishSecurityContext="false" negotiateServiceCredential="false"/>
```

as mentioned in

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dsnotes/2017/04/13/wcf-message-security-limitation-with-tls-1-2-protocol/